# How do use integration to find the area under circle?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have recently come up with a question about the area under circle. I am not sure what to do as circles are not a function. I was thinking to find the area of blue + red, as shown in image, but I don't know how to integrate with circles. Can anyone provides a solution? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the area of the $x,\,y\ge0$ region the two circles enclose, or do you want to double-count where the circles' $x,\,y\ge0$ regions overlap?

Comment: Is this a homework exercise where you are *required* to use integration (either because it says so, or implicitly because you're studying integration), or can you just use trigonometry and geometry? If you must integrate, are you aware there is a function whose plot is a semicircle?

Comment: @ Hetian Fu: Using polar coordinates of an eccentric circle is one way.

Comment: i don't know a lot about polar coordinates but thank you for your advice

Comment: Challenge: Now find the red area alone!

Comment: Which area do you need to compute ? That of the union of the circles ? This is unclear.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: sum of the red and blue

Comment: First deal with blue area. Write the equation of circle which contains arc $ALJ_2$ and express it in the form $x=f(y) $ where $x\geq 0$ and you can integrate this between $y=0$ and $y=y_0$ where $y_0>0$ and $f(y_0)=0$. The red area can be obtained as a difference of two areas (which themselves can be evaluated as integrals).

Comment: You may update your post with your work based on the hint I gave. Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Not involving integration, but using triangle and circle areas directly. We can compare and recognize respective terms by integration.

By intersection of $y=x$ with the eccentric circle equation (omitted) we get

$$ x_L=y_L= \frac{3+\sqrt{ 89}}{2};\; TX= 10-7=3 ; $$

In the construction below due to symmetry one half of the required area is LTB, shown in green+ yellow parts:

[image]

$$ =\dfrac12\cdot TX\cdot y_L + \dfrac12 \cdot \dfrac{\pi}{4}\cdot XB^2 =\dfrac12\cdot TX\cdot y_L +  \dfrac{7^2}{2}\cdot\tan^{-1}\frac{y_L}{x_L-3}$$
which you can calculate numerically.

Comment: not quite sure what do u mean by 1/2*π/4*49

Comment: Very nice indeed, but $LXB$ should be more than $\pi/4$. In fact $LXB=\pi/4+TLX$

Comment: My point was that the Centre angle (for yellow sector) is more than $45^{\circ}$. The angle $LTB$ is $45^{\circ}$.

Comment: Please fix the angle part of the sector. Instead of $\pi/4$ it should be $\arctan (y_L/(x_L-3))$.

Comment: Thanks about pointing out the last line error, fixed it.

Comment: Hetian Fu: Sorry about error in last line. Paramanand Singh pointed it out. Hope rest is ok.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh. Can we delete the simple comments before the error?

Answer (score 1):

A sketch:

The arc $AL$ has equation $y=\sqrt{49-x^2}+3$; the arc $LB$ has equation $y=\sqrt{49-(x-3)^2}$. You can show these meet at $x=x_0:=\frac{3+\sqrt{89}}{2}$. Integrate the first function from $0$ to $x_0$, then the second from $x_0$ to $10$, using$$\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\;dx=\tfrac12(a^2\arcsin\tfrac{x}{a}+x\sqrt{a^2-x^2})+C.$$

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: why is the end of arc AL equation −3, isn't it +3?

Comment: @HetianFu Thanks; fixed.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The circle on the $x$-axis is
$(x- 3)^2 + y^2= 49$. In polar coordinates, it is
$$r (\theta) = 3\cos t +\sqrt{9\cos^2 t+40}
$$
Then, the total area is

$$A= 2\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac12r^2 (\theta)\>d\theta 
=\frac32 \left(\sqrt{89}+3\right) + 49\tan^{-1}\frac {\sqrt{89}+3}{\sqrt{89}-3}
$$

Comment: i am not that good with polar coordinates but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Find the abscissa/ordinate of the point $L$ by intersection, then compute the area of the curvilinear triangle $WLA$ by the integral

$$I=\int_0^{x_L}(\sqrt{7^2-x^2}-y_L)\,dx.$$ The answer is $2I$ plus the area of the square $T_1J_2LW$.

[image]